How to use supabase with Next.Js 14 for Auth?
I am setting up supabase auth in my Next.Js 14 app using the supabase docs. From the docs, it is unclear how they'd want us to share user data in the entire app in both server & client components.
The flow that I want to build in my auth is as follows:

User sign up via email/password OR oAuth (google, github etc)
User login
Upon successful login, fetch user data which will be used in the entire app all the time so I'd have to store it in redux or context etc. This data is crucial to even show the very first page of my app so it has to be fetched right after login and before the user is redirected to the actual dashboard which has authentication required.

This is what I've currently built using supabase docs:
/auth/login/page.tsx
import { login } from "../actions";

export default function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required />
        <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" required />
        <button formAction={login}>Log in</button>
        <br />
      </form>
      <>
        Dont have an account ?
        <a href="/auth/sign-up">
          <button>Sign up</button>
        </a>
      </>
    </>
  );
}


/auth/sign-up/page.tsx
import { signup } from "../actions";

export default function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <form>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required />
      <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
      <input id="password" name="password" type="password" required />
      <button formAction={signup}>Sign up</button>
    </form>
  );
}


/auth/actions.ts
"use server";

import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

import { createClient } from "@/app/utils/supabase/server";

export async function login(formData: FormData) {
  const supabase = createClient();

  // type-casting here for convenience
  // in practice, you should validate your inputs
  const data = {
    email: formData.get("email") as string,
    password: formData.get("password") as string,
  };

  const { error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword(data);

  if (error) {
    console.log("Login error: " + error);
    redirect("/auth/login?message=could-not-authenticate-user");
  }

  revalidatePath("/", "layout");
  redirect("/");
}

export async function signup(formData: FormData) {
  const supabase = createClient();

  // type-casting here for convenience
  // in practice, you should validate your inputs
  const data = {
    email: formData.get("email") as string,
    password: formData.get("password") as string,
  };

  const { error } = await supabase.auth.signUp(data);

  if (error) {
    console.log("Sign up", error);
    redirect("/auth/sign-up?message=could-not-signup-user");
  }

  revalidatePath("/", "layout");
  redirect("/");
}

/auth/confirm/route.ts
import { type EmailOtpType } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
import { type NextRequest } from "next/server";

import { createClient } from "@/app/utils/supabase/server";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
  const token_hash = searchParams.get("token_hash");
  const type = searchParams.get("type") as EmailOtpType | null;
  const next = searchParams.get("next") ?? "/";

  if (token_hash && type) {
    const supabase = createClient();

    const { error } = await supabase.auth.verifyOtp({
      type,
      token_hash,
    });
    if (!error) {
      // redirect user to specified redirect URL or root of app
      redirect(next);
    }
  }

  // redirect the user to an error page with some instructions
  redirect("/error");
}


/utils/supabase/client.ts
import { createBrowserClient } from "@supabase/ssr";

export function createClient() {
  return createBrowserClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!
  );
}

/utils/supabase/server.ts
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
import { createServerClient, type CookieOptions } from "@supabase/ssr";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export function createClient() {
  const cookieStore = cookies();

  return createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        getAll() {
          return cookieStore.getAll();
        },
        setAll(cookiesToSet) {
          try {
            cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value, options }) =>
              cookieStore.set(name, value, options)
            );
          } catch {
            // The `setAll` method was called from a Server Component.
            // This can be ignored if you have middleware refreshing
            // user sessions.
          }
        },
      },
    }
  );
}

/utils/supabase/middleware.ts
import { createServerClient } from "@supabase/ssr";
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function updateSession(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log("Somehow I am coning here");
  let supabaseResponse = NextResponse.next({
    request,
  });

  const supabase = createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        getAll() {
          return request.cookies.getAll();
        },
        setAll(cookiesToSet) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
          cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value, options }) =>
            request.cookies.set(name, value)
          );
          supabaseResponse = NextResponse.next({
            request,
          });
          cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value, options }) =>
            supabaseResponse.cookies.set(name, value, options)
          );
        },
      },
    }
  );

  const {
    data: { user },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

  if (
    !user &&
    !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/auth/login") &&
    !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/auth/sign-up")
  ) {
    const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
    url.pathname = "/auth/login"; // Redirect to login
    return NextResponse.redirect(url);
  }

  if (user && request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/auth")) {
    const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
    url.pathname = "/console";
    return NextResponse.redirect(url);
  }

  return supabaseResponse;
}


page.tsx (main landing file)
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default function Home() {
  redirect("/console");
}

middleware.ts
import { type NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { updateSession } from "@/app/utils/supabase/middleware";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log("Middleware executed for:", request.nextUrl.pathname);
  return await updateSession(request);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // "/((?!_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|.*\\.(?:svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$).*)",
    "/console/:path*",
    "/auth/:path*",
  ],
};


Now what I want is: There a /console folder in my app that I need protected and I also want the entire user data, i.e. the data I get upon login from supabase and the additional request that I make to fetch further data of user like his roles etc which are from different tables.
I'd want to store this data in redux or context, without having to refetch it again and again everytime I open a new server component
